# Setting an attribute property to the type of the decorated class

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

Is it possible to get the decorated class' type inside of the custom attribute's class?
For example:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ViewAttribute : ExportAttribute
{

    public object TargetRegion { get; set; }
    public Type ViewModel { get; set; }
    public Type Module { get; set; }

    public ViewAttribute()
        : base(typeof(UserControl))
    {
        Module = GetDecoratedClassType(); //I need this method
    }
}
```

In the following example GetDecoratedClassType() would return HomeView

```
[View]
HomeView MyHomeView { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299214/get-member-to-which-attribute-was-applied-from-inside-attribute-constructor), i tend to agree, at the point of reflection you should have access to the member info that the attribute is applied to.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you add it as an argument in the constructor?

```
public class ViewAttribute : ExportAttribute
{    
    public object TargetRegion { get; set; }
    public Type ViewModel { get; set; }
    public Type Module { get; set; }

    public ViewAttribute(Type decoratedClassType)
        : base(typeof(UserControl))
    {
        Module = decoratedClassType
    }
}

[View(typeof(HomeView))]
HomeView MyHomeView { get; set; }
```

I know it's not exactly elegant, but would that suffice? (And you should probably make the setter for Module private)

Comment: A private setter can still be accessed via reflection. To circumvent that, you could make `Module` a 'getter only' property with a `readonly` backing field ...