# Using the name of a generic type in a class attribute

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class which needs to use the name of one of its type arguments in a class attribute. I don't know how to access the class name in that context

I've tried using `typeof(TMsg).Name` but VS shows an error saying

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Currently my code looks like this:

```cs
[MessageBase(typeof(TMsg).Name)]
    public abstract class DDSMessageAbstract<TMsg/*, TReader, TWriter, TMsgBase, TSupport*/> : MessageBaseForDDS
    where TMsg : new()
...
```

My question is, is there a way for me to use the actual name of `TMsg` or  must I define this attribute for each inheriting class?

Comment: What is `MessageBase`? Can you modify it?

Comment: Change `[MessageBase(typeof(TMsg).Name)]` to `[MessageBase(typeof(TMsg))]`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I can't change existing code but I can for example add a constructor

Comment: @ZoharPeled That would still show an error, as I can't use "typeof" inside an attribute

Comment: @Efi can you change the class that uses the attribute?
Somewhere in your code there must be a place where you have the instance of your class inspected to check if your class was decorated with an attribute. There using the instance get the type and extract the generic type (doing so you get the name).

Comment: The attribute `DebuggerDisplay` can display property values at runtime. Perhaps you can find something here(i.e. `[DebuggerDisplay("TheTypeILookFor={PropertyThatReturnstypeofT}")]`).

Comment: @Norcino That's an interesting idea, I'll give it a try soon

Comment: This seems like an X/Y question to me...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/47549711/9338645 as possible help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer might be you could not do that.

First, the generics is for your class instead of your attribute. so you can't use

```
MessageBase(typeof(TMsg)
```

The values into `attributes` are limited to simple types; for example, basic constants (including strings) and `typeof`.

From ECMA 334v4:

> §24.1.3 Attribute parameter types
>
> The types of positional and named
>   parameters for an attribute class are
>   limited to the *attribute parameter
>   types*, which are:
>
> - One of the following types: `bool`, `byte`, `char`,
>     `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, `short`, `string`.
> - The type `object`.
> - The type `System.Type`.
> - An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the
>     types in which it is nested (if any)
>     also have public accessibility.
> - Single-dimensional arrays of the above
>     types.

[ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf)